# Multiply elements in the Spark RDD with each other

Tags: scala, apache-spark, iterator, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

In one of the problems I've faced when running an Apache Spark job is to multiply each element in the RDD with each other.
Simply put, I want to do something similar to this,

[image]

Currently, I'm doing this using 2 iterators for each 'foreach'. My gut feeling is that this can be done in a much efficient manner.

```
for (elementOutSide <- iteratorA) {
  for (elementInside <- iteratorB) {
    if (!elementOutSide.get(3).equals(elementInside.get(3))) {
      val multemp = elementInside.getLong(3) * elementOutSide.getLong(3)
      ....
      ...

}}}
```

Can anyone help me in correcting and improving the situation?? Thanks in advance .. !!

Comment: I think you are looking for a regular cartesian join.

Comment: BTW, your implementation doesn't really fit the requirement - it compares the actual _elements_ and not their _indices_ - that would work if and only if the records of the original RDD are _unique_.

Comment: They are unique, The RDD is constructed using a sql query that guarantees that.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by comments, this is a cartesian join. Here's how it can be done on an `RDD[(Int, String)]`, where we're interested in the multiplication of every two non-identical `Int`s:

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, String)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "aa"),
  (2, "ab"),
  (3, "ac")
))

// use "cartesian", then "collect" to map only relevant results
val result: RDD[Int] = rdd.cartesian(rdd).collect {
  case ((t1: Int, _), (t2: Int, _)) if t1 != t2 => t1 * t2
}
```

Note: this implementation assumes input records are unique, as instructed. If they aren't, you can perform the cartesian join and the mapping on the result of `rdd.zipWithIndex` while comparing the indices instead of the values.

Comment: Hi Tzach, it is giving the output like below
<br>
scala> result.collect
result14: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 2, 6, 3, 6)
<br>
Is it right according to your logic ?
I know it is a old post but still it would be helpful to others.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the desired result: (1*2, 1*3, 2*1, 2*3, 3*1, 3*2)